# excel sums field overlap other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't know if this is a trivial problem but it is driving me nuts. I have two columns like this:

```
| A |B|
|   |5|
|   |3|
|100|2|
|   |5|
|   |2|
|   |3|
```

In column A all cells are merged and I use the values of column B to calculate a percentage. I have to select all cells in column B. As soon as I enter "=SUM(" and start clicking on the cells I need I have an overlap in column A which covers my values in column B so I can't see the cells in column B. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Increase column widths?

Comment: Hmm. I have a lot of documents which are formatted that way. I'd rather not change the widths.

Comment: manually typing the cell ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go somewhere in column C and type the formula, but don't press Enter. When it's complete, press F2 to switch from `enter` mode to `edit` mode, then shift-Home to highlight the entire formula. Ctrl-X to cut it, Esc to cancel typing. Then just paste the formula where you want it.

Comment: ok. will try that thx.